# Lombok setter for injected static variables

Tags: spring, setter, lombok

I have this field which now I want to inject:

```
public class MyConstants {
    public final static String SOME_CONST = "someConts";
    public final static String INJECTED_CONST = "injectedConst"; //<--- I want to inject this!

}
```

So, apart from removing `final`, I've read [this](https://mkyong.com/spring/spring-inject-a-value-into-static-variables/) article on how to inject values into static variables, resulting in:

```
public class MyConstants {
    public final static String SOME_CONST = "someConts";
    @NonNull public static String INJECTED_CONST;

    @Value("${const.injectedConst}")
    public void setInjectedConst(String injectedConst) {
        INJECTED_CONST = injectedConst;
    }
}
```

Great, how can I "Lombok-ize" this by using `@Setter`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Value("${const.injectedConst}"))
```

this would create the constructor with Value annotation on top. You would need to make the field final again, though. I don't understand exactly what is your need, so I don't know if this would solve your problem. Please let me know.

Comment: Even better if I have to use `final` again. The need is to inject that value without changing the variable (`static` and `final`).

Comment: does this work for you? if so, please accept my answer